# Yesod migrating custom data types

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I have an Entity called User

```
User
  ident Text
  ...
  status Status Default=Claimed
```

Status is a data type I made.  I have already rows in my Postgresql table so I get a yesod devel migration error when trying to compile

```
Migrating: ALTER TABLE "user" ADD COLUMN "status" VARCHAR NOT NULL
31/Oct/2013:07:17:19 -0500 [Debug#SQL] "ALTER TABLE \"user\" ADD COLUMN \"status\" VARCHAR NOT NULL" [] @(persistent-1.2.2.0:Database.Persist.Sql.Raw     ./Database/Persist/Sql/Raw.hs:37:5)
devel.hs: SqlError {sqlState = "23502", sqlExecStatus = FatalError, sqlErrorMsg = "column \"status\" contains null values", sqlErrorDetail = "", sqlErrorHint = ""}
```

This was expected and I know that now I should go to psql and do the migration myself. 
I thought the migration code should look like this:
    ALTER TABLE "user" ADD COLUMN "status" VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT Claimed
but I get an error saying column Claimed does not exist.  How do I add a column with a default value that isn't a Text or a number?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your alter query says that the new column type is varchar hence the default value will be a varchar (String).

```
ALTER TABLE "user" ADD COLUMN "status" VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Claimed'
```

Comment: That's right, except I recall that in double quote I also got an error.  In PG Sting values are single quoted.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue myself.  It was only a PostgreSql error.  Claimed had do be single quoted like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "user" ADD COLUMN "status" VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Claimed'
```

In PG single quotes are for string constants while double quotes specify case sensitive identifiers.  In this case Claimed unquoted is considered an identifier, that's why I got a column <...> doesn't exist error. 
[Here is the PostgresSql documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/static/sql-syntax.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)